# How do I initialization a dictionary without well defined field values

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, initialization

I have a dictionary that's initialized as such:

```
n = 5
myDict = { 'Field1' : 'Hello', 
           'Field2' : [0]*n, 
           'Field3' : [2]*n,
           'Field4' : [4]*n,
           'Field5' : 'World'}
```

I would like to be able to initialize myDict without knowing the value for `n`. And then at a later point in time when `n` is known, update all fields that utilize `n` for assigning list length. I'd prefer not to recreate the dictionary. My first thought would be utilize a ListInit function that returns it's self unless n is set. I believe I've seen a design pattern that's looked something like this before:

```
def ListInit(n=None):
     return n if n else ListInit

myDict = { 'Field1' : 'Hello', 
           'Field2' : [0]*ListInit(), 
           'Field3' : [2]*ListInit(),
           'Field4' : [4]*ListInit(),
           'Field5' : 'World'}

ListInit(5)
```

I know this doesn't work for a multitude of reasons but hopefully it gets the idea across of what this pattern might look like. Thanks!

Comment: It feels like an XY problem. Why can't you create `myDict` after `n` is known? what is the actual problem you try to solve? your approach is somewhere between hard and impossible.

Comment: ...or maybe update the dictionary with required fields when the `n` is known.

Comment: Maybe a dictionary isn't the right tool here. This might make a bit more sense as an class with computed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Hey why not to execute one dictionary that doesnt have any value ar null valuse and print another dictionary with the updated vales when n is not null